# Detect whether a window was opened from the same website

Tags: javascript, html

If I make a link to another part of the site e.g.

```
<a href="foo.html" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

I want to be able to tell in the new window if the user has come via that link, or if they have come directly to that url via a different route. Is that possible?

This is because, if they came from the same site, I can use `window.close();`, but not if they came via a different route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use `document.referrer`:

```
if(document.referrer){
    // close the window here
    console.log('loaded via navigation')
}else{
    console.log('no navigation');
}
```

or you might want to get the domain name from the referrer:

```
function virtualURL(url) {
    var a=document.createElement('a');
    a.href=url;
    return a.hostname;
}

if(virtualURL(document.referrer)  === window.location.hostname){
    // close the window here
    console.log('loaded via navigation')
}else{
    console.log('nope');
}
```

Here in the above code `virtualURL(document.referrer)` will return the hostname of the last visited page. So, you can match that with the current application's host name, if they match then you can close the window.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking at all sorts of alternative solutions like passing variables from the parent to it's children. Thanks :)

Comment: That could be another solution. and You are welcome.